# Breakpoints values are overriden by mobile value on tailwindcss

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a problem for which I have not yet found any questions anywhere.

When I use paddings or margins for mobile and I want to change these paddings/margins on larger screens, the base value I set for mobile stays and overrides my specific values at the different breakpoints.

Here is what I can see in the debugger:
As you can see with the py-3 value, it stays and overrides my py-0 which applies to the md breakpoint.

---

This is on mobile version

[image: py-3]

---

This is on desktop version

[image: py-3 override py-0 on md breakpoint]

---

This is my code, the `py-3` and `md:py-0` are applied on the buttons:

```js
<div className="...">
    {languages.map((lng) => (
        <button className="px-2.5 py-3 md:py-0 text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500 text-center">
            {lng.name}
        </button>
    ))}
</div>
```

I'm on a classic next.js install with taildwindcss without any extends/theme replacement. Nowhere in my css file do I override these classes.

Is there something I missing ?

EDIT: I tried to apply an "!" in front of my `py-0` like that : `md:!py-0` but it's stil the same. Even if the !important keyword is correctly added, it's still overriden.

Answer (score 0):

The `!important` assignement overrides the following (and thus in normal case
overwriting) `@media { }`

Get your `.py-3 { }` displayed correctly *without* the need of `!important`.